# Test access to WindRiver/VxWorks license server?

Tags: license-key, wind-river-workbench

I'm having trouble debugging a WindRiver build system where the build machine seems unable to obtain a license from the WindRiver license server.  Is there a tool that allows me to run a "get me a license" check without having to run a complete build?

Answer (score 2):

you can try on the client side, to run from the command line the command -lmutil stat, this will ping the license server and return a response.

regards.

Comment: Thanks for that tip.  Off to try it out!  Failing this I discovered the following about the server which might help others.  The server uses at least 2 different ports.  The first request goes to one daemon, this responds with information about a second daemon and a request ot the second daemon validates the license.  The first port used is TCP/27000 followed by one of UDP/44660 or TCP/54788 (the later in my case).  If you catch exchanges in Wireshark, you can see the ports as plain text.

Comment: Getting "Error getting status: Cannot find license file. (-1,359:2 "No such file or directory")" from lmutil.  Looks like it thinks the local client system is supposed to be a server.  Any suggestions?  I have tried "-s <server-hostname>".

Comment: @PaulDSmith btw did you know they have a site where you can request support for windriver issues? support2.windriver.com

Comment: Thanks Emanuel; I'll check it out next time I have a WindRiver issue.

Answer (score 2):

Paul, in this case, if you're using another machine as a license server, first be sure that the server is up and running, after that on the client machine, set the environment variable WRSD_LICENSE_FILE = 27000@ and test.

Comment: I can confirm that this does seem to work.   Set the environment variable `WSRD_LICENSE_FILE=27000@<license-server>` and run `lmutil stat` and I get back the status of the license server.  Thanks Emanuel Rojas Agüero

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `lmutil` directly without setting the environment variable, executing:

```
lmutil.exe lmstat -a -c 27001@myserver.mydomain.com
```